# For which $n\in \Bbb N$ is $H_n:=\{\alpha^2\mid \alpha\in S_n\}\cong A_n?$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups, group-isomorphism

I'm reading "*Contemporary Abstract Algebra,"* by Gallian.

This is inspired by Exercise 5.73 and Exercise 5.74 *ibid*. **I have a preference for answers using only the tools available in the textbook so far; lemmas may be established, though, and are actually welcome.**

> **Question:** For which $n\in \Bbb N$ is $$H_n:=\{\alpha^2\mid \alpha\in S_n\}\cong A_n?\tag{$\mathcal{H}_n$}$$ Here $S_n$ is the symmetric group of order $n!$ and $A_n$ is the alternating group of order $\frac{n!}{2}$.

*Thoughts.*

[The OEIS isn't helpful so far.](https://oeis.org/search?q=4%2C5+alternating+group+squared&sort=&language=english&go=Search) This is probably because the only data I have is that $(\mathcal{H}_n)$ is true for $n=4$ and $n=5$ (by Exercise 5.73) but not $n=6$ (by Exercise 5.74).

This seems like a natural question to ask, so I doubt it's original here.

I think $(\mathcal{H}_1)$ and $(\mathcal{H}_2)$ are true by inspection but $(\mathcal{H}_3)$ is a case where I just have to shut up and calculate.

For $n\ge 7$, perhaps the lack of an isomorphism is inherited from the falsehood of $(\mathcal{H}_6)$.

Please help :)

Comment: Well $(1,2)(3,4,5,6)$ cannot be a square for any $n \ge 6$. In fact $\cong A_n$ is equivalent to $= A_n$ in this question.

Comment: Thank you, @DerekHolt; please would you upgrade that comment to an answer? It's so I can close the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $H_n\subseteq A_n$, if they have the same cardinality they must be equal.  So, $H_n\cong A_n$ iff $H_n=A_n$.  Now note that the square of an odd cycle is a cycle of the same length, and the square of an even cycle is a product of two disjoint cycles of half the length.  In particular, even cycles in a square must come in pairs of the same length (since they can only come from the square of an even cycle).  So, a product of two disjoint cycles of different even lengths is an element of $A_n$ which cannot be a square.  Such a product exists as long as $n\geq 6$, so $H_n\neq A_n$ for any $n\geq 6$.